# How to float to the right of, and level with block-level elements

Tags: css, css-position

I want a web page that looks like this ...

```css
header {
  border-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 5px;
  background-color: red;
}

p {
  background-color: yellow;
}

header #btnLogIn {
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  right: 170px;
  top: 40px;
}

header #btnGoogleLogIn {
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Site Title</h1>
  <button id="btnLogIn" type="button">Log in</button>
  <button id="btnGoogleLogIn" type="button">Log in with Google</button>
</header>
<hr/>
<p>Some text</p>
```

The buttons need to be on the same horizontal level as the h1 header, floating to the right, with some nice margin in between. The button captions can change dynamically (via language selection), so any solution with hard-coded `right` property values is a fail.

How can I get the buttons to float to the right, on the same row as the h1 element, in a way that is independent of button width? The solution needs to be css.

Comment: You can use flexbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flexbox like this:

```css
header {
  border-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

p {
  background-color: yellow;
}

header button {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

header h1 {
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Site Title</h1>
  <button id="btnLogIn" type="button">Log in</button>
  <button id="btnGoogleLogIn" type="button">Log in with Google</button>
</header>
<hr>
<p>Some text</p>
```

Comment: Unfortunately in your solution, when someone will decide to move `btnLogIn` to the right of `btnGoogleLogIn` - it will break. Not too clean IMO.

Comment: @sarneeh we simply move the margin auto to the title instead ;)

Comment: Indeed, that would work :) But in this case you're again limiting adding something next to the `h1`. But! If it's not a case than it's alright to use this solution :)

Comment: @sarneeh `But in this case you're again limiting adding something next to the h1` --> if the HTML is changing, CSS also :) am not limiting, but there is no CSS that work with any HTML structure like we want. We should always adapt it ... i can provide you with another solution that consider any element you add if you ;)

Comment: Of course you are right. But if there's a possibility, it's better to create a solution that will be more flexible and won't provide eventual issues later on. If it doesn't come with a great cost of course, because then we're coming to something called "over-engineering" :)

Comment: @sarneeh and the solution i provided is perfectly flexible .. as if you will add another element you simply have to edit a small CSS to add the auto margin to it which is extremely easy to do ... by the way in your question you specified h1 and buttons and no other elements ... so if it's not always the case you may edit the question to include how can the HTML evolve and i will consider it ;)

Comment: Check out my answer - this kind of flexibility is something that I like to have to reduce even the little edits which you're talking about. Additionally, IMO it's a lot easier to read than having a `header h1 { margin-right: auto; }` :) But that's just my preference, I don't want to say that my solution is better than yours, just wanted to share my point of view :)

Comment: @sarneeh but in your answer you changed the html completely :) so it's not a matter of best answer or not

Comment: And what's wrong in changing the HTML? It's the same as changing the CSS in your case. I just like to have everything readable from the beginning. The initial markup from the question doesn't say anything about that title is aligned to left and the rest to the right. And that's something that could be improved and is what I've proposed in my answer. Strong html-css coupling is not a good practice for code readability and certainly not for maintainability.

Comment: @sarneeh i never said is wrong to change HTML ;) i said it's not a matter of better or not ... you provided a complete new code that do the same ... and by providing a new code you changed the meaning of the quesiton and we no more have to deal with block element with button ... so i don't think it's more flexible for the OP to change the code or not, this what i meant

Comment: Well, that's true :)

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox is the answer:

**HTML:**

```
<header>
  <div class="header-left">
    <h1>Site Title</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="header-right">
    <button class="btn" type="button">Log in</button>
    <button class="btn" type="button">Log in with Google</button>
  </div>
</header>
<hr/>
<p>Some text</p>
```

**CSS:**

```
header {
  border-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

header .btn {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

p {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you?

```css
header {
  border-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
header h1 {
  flex: 1;
}

header button {
  margin: 0 1em;
}
p {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Site Title</h1>
  <button id="btnLogIn" type="button">Log in</button>
  <button id="btnGoogleLogIn" type="button">Log in with Google</button>
</header>
<hr/>
<p>Some text</p>
```